# Can the first key-value-pair in a URL query be empty?

Tags: string, url, web, keyvaluepair

I've recently coded an AJAX logic where I purposefully generate URLs that start with `?&`, like this:

http://www.freeformatter.com/url-parser-query-string-splitter.html?&r=fb&frage=2&debug&mid=1234&rid=abcd&h=3

I admit, that decision is partly based on laziness but honestly, I don't see any concern with this, from a technical standpoint.

Now, a colleague of mine asked me today how safe-to-use this is in regards to support of old/shitty browsers (such as IE **cough, cough**). Since I didn't find anything in the internet, I'm asking you guys/gals.

Comment: The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) is really, really terse. If you try to take it to the letter, then & is a separator, which is not how you're using it. Because the spec is not rigorous enough I think you have no answer and you would have to try it in all browsers that you need. If I were you, I would stop being lazy.

Comment: But it's not erroneous. If I were to write `?a=b&c=d&` instead, that wouldn't cause an error either. So why would it here?

Comment: There are times when it's okay to be lazy. In moderation, of course. Too much pressure isn't good for your health.

Comment: the spec only says that. It's very little. Now imagine what any programmer on earth might understand by "separator". If you take the word strictly, then it means that it must be between something and something, where something isn't nothing. You can't be sure that someone else didn't take it strictly and that it doesn't cause an error. If you know which software will parse your URL-encoded forms, then it's ok. And it won't be browsers, right? Typically forms are parsed by server-side software.

Comment: It's probably less work to stop doing it like that than to try to figure out if it's ok in all cases. If you want to be lazy, be seriously lazy.